# Rspec pass test in ruby testing

Tags: ruby, dictionary, rspec

I have an Rspec test as follow:

```
it "calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really" do
  solution.analyze_file

  expect(solution.highest_count_words_across_lines).to be nil

  solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

  words_found = solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
  expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"] 
end
```

It gives an error

```
Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
     Failure/Error: words_found solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
   NoMethodError:
       undefined method `highest_wf_words' for "really":String
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:38:in `map'
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

On the other hand if I write this test without

```
.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
```

Then it passed.

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines = ["really","will","it"]
```

How can I make this test to pass, while includding the mapping:

```
.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten?
```

Comment: Can you please properly format your code/error messages? And rephrase your question title?

Comment: I update my question.Kindly see now

Comment: There error is saying that you are calling `'really'.highest_wf_words`.   What does the method highest_wf_words() look like?

Comment: Please post the code for the methods `highest_count_words_across_lines` and `highest_wf_words`. And, in the future, go for _much_ shorter method names

Comment: Both of these are instance variables

Comment: Your map statement basically says `map { |x| x.highest_wf_words }`. Is that a viable method for the string `'results'`? If you mean to _push_ to the instance var (assuming it is an array), you need to say `map { |x| @highest_wf_words.push x }`

Comment: This is fixed test case.I cant change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`solution.highest_count_words_across_lines` is an array of strings. When you do this: `solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words)` you are calling `highest_wf_words` on each of the array items, and that method is not defined for a String (that is what the error message says).

I guess that in fact you want something like this instead:

```
words_found = solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map( |x| highest_wf_words(x)).flatten
```

---

UPDATE

if the aim of your mapping is for the `words_found` only to include `highest_wf_words`, assuming that this is an array, here's how you can do it:

```
words_found = solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.flatten & highest_wf_words
```

.

```
[1,2,3] & [2,3,4]
=> [2, 3]
```

Comment: I accept this question because it is correct.It helps me to understand.But my issue is that I cant change this
solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words)
Which change I do it matches?